# Issue with monitor switching to external even though none are hooked up

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm currently using my Windows 7 HP DV6000 laptop. For whatever reason the screen decides to automatically go blank as if its displaying on an external monitor, but i don't have any hooked up. I close the lid, reopen it and the display is back to normal. I'm not sure what to make of this. I've reinstalled both graphic drivers, the intel hd 4000 and my nvidia geforce gt 650m for gaming.

Has anybody experienced this issue before?

- Matt

Comment: Good question - I don't have the answer. The only thing I can think is that you might accidentally be hitting the key combination that switches display; unlikely. Might be worth explaining when it happens. While you're typing? Sitting dormant...?

Comment: its completely random when it happens. i could be while typing, while streaming, while gaming. there's no rhyme or reason that i can find thus far.

Comment: Strange. Could it then be something is deciding that it wants to display on the extended desktop. Again, another longshot. You'll be lucky if someone has experienced this themselves and bothers to answer!

Answer (score 0):

- Besides hitting the fn+?? that might be the laptop's display switch
  shortcut, could it be caused by winKey +P (does the same thing).
- Could your keyboard be dirty, or some key malfunctioning?
- Also it's weird for the pc to switch when no extra monitor installed,
  right click on desktop and check the Screen resolution window, how
  many screens appear there, try hitting "detect". Only one monitor
  should be enabled.
- Lastly, does your external display port function normally? can you connect an external monitor? Anyway plugging and unplugging some monitor cable on your
  display port (HDMI or VGA) a couple of times, maybe some dirt got in there and simulates the connection of a new monitor. Especially if you have an HDMI port, the regular action for windows is to switch to the external monitor on connection.